# How to find the values of a column such that no values in another column takes value greater than 3

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the values corresponding to a column such that no values in another column takes value greater than 3.

For example, in the following dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6], 'c':[4,3,5,4,3,5,4,3,3]})`

I want the values of the column 'a' for which all the values of 'c' which are greater than 3.

I think groupby is the correct way to do it. My below code comes closer to it.

```
df.groupby('a')['c'].max()>3
a
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

The above code gives me a boolean frame. How can I get the values of 'a' such that it is true.
 I want my output to be [1,3]

Is there a better and efficient way to get this on a very large data frame (with more than 30 million rows).

Comment: You dont want `df.a[df.c>3]`, do you?

Comment: This sentence *I want the values of the column 'a' for which **all** the values of 'c' which are greater than 3.* does not go along with *I want my output to be [1,3]*

Comment: Hope you can see my answer , And I will delete it shortly due to down-vote

Comment: Question is not clear. You state a desired output which apparently is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Other people have already made some good points. Please clarify your question, instead of ignoring all comments and focusing only on getting a solution.

Comment: @YOBEN_S You have 180,000 rep, what amount of downvotes could possibly have an effect? Was there actual vote brigading?

Comment: @TitoOrt I think your answer is the best and simplest one.

Comment: @Shew Is that what you were trying to do?

Comment: @AMC.  Yes. the accepted answer and the comment from TitoOrt are very similar. I just have to use unique on the output of TitoOrt's comment

Comment: @Shew Which part were you struggling with, then? I’m trying to think of an existing post.

Comment: @AMC. I did not know that one could do `df.a[condition]` I came across only `df[condition]` so far. That is why I tried with groupby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code I see that you actually want to output:

- group keys for each group (*df* grouped by *a*),
- where no value in *c* column (within the current group) is greater than *3*.

In order to get some non-empty result, let's change the source DataFrame to:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  4  4
1  2  5  1
2  3  6  5
3  1  4  4
4  2  5  2
5  3  6  5
6  1  4  4
7  2  5  2
8  3  6  3
```

For readability, let's group *df* by *a* and print each group.
The code to do it:

```
for key, grp in df.groupby('a'):
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

gives result:

```
Group: 1
   a  b  c
0  1  4  4
3  1  4  4
6  1  4  4

Group: 2
   a  b  c
1  2  5  1
4  2  5  2
7  2  5  2

Group: 3
   a  b  c
2  3  6  5
5  3  6  5
8  3  6  3
```

And now take a look at each group.
Only group *2* meets the condition that each element in *c* column
is less than *3*.

So actually you need a *groupby* and *filter*, passing only groups
meeting the above condition:

To get **full rows** from the "good" groups, you can run:

```
df.groupby('a').filter(lambda grp: grp.c.lt(3).all())
```

getting:

```
   a  b  c
1  2  5  1
4  2  5  2
7  2  5  2
```

But you want only values from *a* column, without repetitions.
So extend the above code to:

```
df.groupby('a').filter(lambda grp: grp.c.lt(3).all()).a.unique().tolist()
```

getting:

```
[2]
```

Note that your code: `df.groupby('a')['c'].max() > 3` is wrong,
as it marks with *True* groups for which *max* is **greater** than *3*
(instead of ">" there should be "<").

So an alternative solution is:

```
res = df.groupby('a')['c'].max()<3
res[res].index.tolist()
```

giving the same result.

Yet another solution can be based on a list comprehension:

```
[ key for key, grp in df.groupby('a') if grp.c.lt(3).all() ]
```

Details:

- `for key, grp in df.groupby('a')` - creates groups,
- `if grp.c.lt(3).all()` - filters groups,
- `key` (at the start) - adds particular group key to the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6], 'c':[4,3,5,4,3,5,4,3,3]})

#Write a function to find values greater than 3 if found return.
def grt(x):
   for i in x:
      if i>3:
         return(i)

#Groupby column a and call function grt       
p = {'c':grt}
grp = df.groupby(['a']).agg(p)
print(grp)
```